# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a rel="next" href="/events?page=2">

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, scrapy

I want to go the next page by click on a link with a span tag inside, using selenium python  but stack somewhere. please kindly need your help.

 **Main part code**

```
driver.get('https://shoobs.com/find-events')
selector= '//*[@class="pagination"]/span[7]/a'
links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=160).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH,selector))
links.click()

driver.quit()
```

**Error**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a rel="next" href="/events?page=2">...</a> is not clickable at point (865, 924). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cookie-banner">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)
```

Once browser opens if I scroll down it works properly and routed to next page but if I don't scroll down and put as it is it gives the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above mentioned error indicates that you have to execute JavaScript

```
driver.get('https://shoobs.com/find-events')
selector= '//*[@class="pagination"]/span[7]/a'
links = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=160).until(lambda d: d.find_element(By.XPATH,selector))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", links)
```